# Spring WebApplicationContext does not share PropertyPlaceHolder Defined in RootApplicationContext?

Tags: placeholder, applicationcontext

I have a context:property-placeholder defined in my root application context

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:runtime/runtime.properties"
    ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

and the application context is registered in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

and I have a dispatcher-servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispather</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I use one of the place holders in dispatcher-servlet.xml but it does not seem to work:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway path="${myplaceholder}" .../>
```

It seems beans in WebApplicationContext can refer to beans in RootApplicationContext but cannot share placeholders defined in RootApplicationContext?

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

The property-placeholder is actually an bean post processor. It can only apply to beans in the same context. so the property-placeholder defined in root application context won't affect beans in dispatcher-servlet(WebApplicationContext can refer to beans in RootApplicationContext but RootApplicationContext cannot refer to beans in WebApplicationContext).

I solved this problem by using a configuration facade and spring el.

In root application context:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:runtime/runtime.properties"/>   

<bean id="configurations" class="x.y.z.Configurations">
    <property name="inboundGatewayPath" value="${myplaceholder}" />
</bean>
```

In web application context:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway path="#{configurations.inboundGatewayPath}" .../>
```